# why should a condition variable must always associated with a mutex?

Tags: c++, mutex, conditional-statements

Why should condition variable uses a mute together? what't functionality of it? Any detailed answer with examples will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try searching for basic, existing information on the internet, like [the article on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_variable#Condition_variables)? Which part of it is unclear?

Comment: https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#ConVarSignal

Comment: I googled around, and found some article about that, But I'am confused.